# How can I delete, or edit a Facebook Page I created?

Tags: facebook-pages

I created a page for my business, (Fit By DK) but now addresses, and email/web addresses have changed. There are no edit features, and no way to delete the Page and start over. Please help. I can send screenshots if needed.

Comment: It is hard to understand what your problem is without a screenshot. Please use the _Edit_ link and  add screenshots _to your question_. Remember to blur/remove any personal information from the screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to your page, on top, you have the `Admin Panel`. Go under `Edit Page` drop down and click on `Edit Settings`. Last option is `Remove Page` -> `Delete your Page`. Of course you need to have admin role to be able to do so.

[image]

Comment: Thats the problem. There is nowhere for an Admin

Comment: @DavidDKKnight do you have admin privileges?

Comment: I thought I did when I created it in November. Now there's no place for admin or editing.

Comment: Post a screenshot of your settings.

Comment: Sorry, I've been out of town.

Comment: I have the screenshots, but can't determine how to post them.

Comment: @DavidDKKnight if you can't attache them to your main post, place a link to where we can find them.